# EvaporateJS: Always get 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch error after resuming an upload

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, file-upload, multipart, evaporate.js

I use EvaporateJS in full compliance with official documentation and examples.
My server side program works properly for signing v4, and the multipart upload is done properly.

But I have a problem with the pause and resume functions.
When I pause an upload, after resuming it, the first PUT request always gets a `403 (SignatureDoesNotMatch)` error.

After a bit more research, it seems that the reason is that the library sends the wrong `stringToSign` to the server for signing on the first attempt after the resume.

This is last `str_to_sign` before pausing

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 
*20220608T114339Z* 
20220608/default/s3/aws4_request 
**b45c4ca1a7c7744ea2f3b6507bd3452317773cf30b860f4d98de662b8f7a85b6**
```

This is the first str_to_sign after resuming

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
*20220608T114345Z*
20220608/default/s3/aws4_request
**b45c4ca1a7c7744ea2f3b6507bd3452317773cf30b860f4d98de662b8f7a85b6**
```

As you can see above the time has been changed but the canonicalRequest values are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the line `1815` of the `evaporate.js` should be deleted.

`if (typeof this._cr !== 'undefined') { return this._cr; }`